# Почему метод массива дает разный результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(array1.fill(0, 2, 4));


let arr2 = [6, 7, 8];

console.log( arr2.fill(9, 3, 5) )
```

Comment: Что значит "разный"? ЗЫ. fill не изменяет размера массива, указанные "лишние" индексы игнорятся.

Comment: посмотрите документацию для начала и разберетесь, что значат аргументы, которые вы передаете в метод

Comment: @ThisMan еще раз перечитал документацию, осознал, понял свою ошибку...

Comment: @Akina понял спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии со [справкой](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) данная функция может принимать до трех параметров:

1. Заполняемое значение
2. Индекс начала заполнения
3. Индекс окончания заполнения

---

Применительно к примерам в вопросе

```
array1.fill(0, 2, 4)
```

Будет вставляться `0`, начиная с индекса 2 и заканчивая индексом 4

для массива `[1, 2, 3, 4]` - на индексе 2 находится элемент со значением `3`, то есть начиная с этого элемента будут 0, что и показывается в результате.

---

```
arr2.fill(9, 3, 5)
```

Будет вставляться `9`, начиная с индекса 3 и заканчивая индексом 5

У массива `[6, 7, 8]` нет индекса 3, поэтому вставка и не происходит.

Comment: спасибо за написание ответа, до вашего ответа я понял как работает и вопрос такой возник ваше мнение об этом ресурсе https://learn.javascript.ru/ после его масштабного обновления

Comment: @user345125, мне больше нравится [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/)

Comment: ясно тут ресурс лучше для новичков ...